# Exclude sub-directories A from .gitignore from parent project, knowing that A is ignored in a sub-directory

Tags: git

Please consider the following project:

```
parent
|
|-- .gitignore
|
|-- .git
|
`--legacy
      |
      |-- .gitignore
      |
      |-- .git
      |
       `-- plugins
              |-- forum
              |     |
              |     `-- .git
              | 
              |-- chat
              |     |
              |     `-- .git
              |
               `--editor
                    |
                    `-- .git
```

Currently, **parent** project ignores **legacy** project (**/legacy/** in **.gitignore**), and **legacy** ignores the **plugins** directory (**/plugins/** in **.gitignore**).

From now on, I need `git` of the parent to handle **chat** and **editor** plugins. However the **legacy** project shouldn't be modified.
I've tried adding the following entries in **.gitignore** of **parent**:

```
/legacy/*
!/legacy/plugins/

/legacy/plugins/*
!/legacy/plugins/chat/
```

I can't see **chat** from **parent** directory, so it doesn't work.

What're my options ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/legacy/*
!/legacy/plugins/chat/
```

It looks the same thing, but its not. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Comment: Thanks great answer for a **one level git ignore**, I've got a multilevel one